# How to use AngularJS promises with Cordova Camera correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, asynchronous, angular-promise

I am having a series of functions that need to be executed in a synchronous order. One of these function is to get a picture using the Cordova Camera library from the phone of the user. Another function takes the image source and draws it in the DOM.

I work with Angular promises and the $q library to handle the synchronous execution. However, it seems that it somehow results in not updating the DOM when the functions are executed in order, even though the image was captured successfully and I have the url (ImageData).

To test, I added a function that draws the image on the DOM using the url that has been saved when the image has been captured from the phone. This does work. So there must be a problem with the use of my Angular Promises and handling of it.

How can I resolve this?

**controllers** ($q injected)

```
var sGetImage = function() {

    var imageSrcOutput = "";
    $scope.imageDataSrc = null;

    try {

        imageSrcOutput = CloakService.getImageData()
            .then(function(imageData) {

                //$scope.imageData = imageData;
                $scope.imageDataSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                //$scope.imgURI = $scope.imageDataSrc;

                return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

            });

        // catch any errors with a struddle image
    } catch (error) {

        window.alert("No Image Picked. Drawing Struddle");
        imageSrcOutput = "img/struddle.jpg";
        $scope.imageDataSrc = imageSrcOutput;
    }

    return imageSrcOutput;

}

var sDrawImage = function(imageSrc) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(imageSrc)

    window.alert("drawing image now with: " + imageSrc)
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;
    img.onload = ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

**// execution cycle (in controller)**

```
  sInit() // works fine
  .then( sGetImage ) // image loaded in imageSrcOutput and $scope.imageDataSrc succesfully
  .then( sDrawImage ) // here is the problem, it does not draw the images (tried both imageSrcOutput and $scope.imageDataSrc)
  .then( sAddBanner )
  .catch(function(error) {
      window.alert("Catch Error: " + error)
  })
```

**services** ($cordovaCamera injected)

```
var getImageData = function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var options = getOptions('CAMERA');

    var imageDataOutput = $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        // window.alert(imageData)
        deferred.resolve(imageData)
        return imageData; //todo:check

    }, function(error) {

        deferred.reject(error)
        window.alert(error)

    });

    function getOptions(source) {
        var options = {
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        };
        return options;
    }

    return deferred.promise;
    //return imageDataOutput;
}
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ionic',
    'myApp.config',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp.decorators',
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.routes',
    'myApp.services', 
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ngCordova' // the library to handle the picture
  ])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the problem:

```
img.onload=ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

An `onload` handler needs to be a function. You are executing `ctx.drawImage()` immediately.

Try this:

```
img.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); };
```

FYI, the stuff you are doing with `$q.defer()` in `sDrawImage` (and elsewhere) is unnecessary. If you want to pass `imageSrc` on to the next step, you can just do this:

```
var sDrawImage = function(imageSrc) {
    window.alert("drawing image now with: " + imageSrc)
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSrc;

    return $q(function (resolve) {
        img.onload = function () { 
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
            resolve(imageSrc);
        };
    });
};
```

Any time you think of using `$q.defer()`, you should ask yourself "do I really need this?". 99.5% of the time, the answer should be "No."

Comment: Thank you for the response. 1. Replacing ctx.drawImage did not work as I tried it with another function after sDrawImage in the execution cycle, where I do img.onload = start(). 
2. I added the $q.defer in sDrawImage because when trying it on the phone, it started to draw the image before I had selected anything on my phone. So, the execution cycle went like 1. drawImage and then 2. sGetImage. Adding the defer and resolve helped to resolve it. Perhaps some problems with my first part?

Comment: @AMG I don't understand what you are saying in 1. What is `start()`? For 2, I'm not sure why you got that result, but I guarantee that the `$q.defer()` that you are using in `sDrawImage` and `getImageData` is unnecessary.

Comment: Applying  both tips worked now! Think I had a typo. However, it does not work for my second function drawSomethingElse and then adding a banner on the other image. Do you have tips on how to handle chained executions properly? So, execute function 2 only when the full function 1 has been executed.

Comment: @AMG So you want to execute `sAddBanner` only after the image created in `sDrawImage` has finished loading?

Comment: Yes indeed! Didnt see your comment. Still haven't solved it :( @JLRishe

Comment: @AMG I've modified `sDrawImage` so that it returns a promise that resolves when the image is done loading. Please see if that helps.